Showing that each natural, $x$, of an ordered field can be uniquely represented in the form: $x= n\cdot 1_F$, where $n$ is a natural of $\mathbb{R}$
Problem statement:
Show by induction that each natural element $x$ of an ordered field $F$ can be uniquely represented as $x=n\cdot 1_F$, where $n$ is the natural number in $\mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $1_F$ is the unity in $F$; that is, $x$ is the sum of $n$ unities.
Conversely, show that each such $n\cdot 1_F$ is a natural element of $F$. Finally, show that, for $m,n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{R}}$, we have
\begin{align*}
 m<n\;\; \text{iff}\;\; mx<nx, 
\end{align*}
Context:
This is a challenging problem from the book, Basic Concepts in Mathematics by Elias Zakon.
He defines Natural elements of a field $F$ as such:
A Subset $S$ of a field $F$ is called inductive iff:

$1\in S$ ($S$ contains the unity element of $F$) and,
$(\forall x \in S)\;\; x+1\in S$.

Define the natural elements, $N$, of field $F$ to be the intersection of all such subsets. We then obtain the following:

$1 \in N$ and
$(\forall x \in N)\;\; x+1 \in N.$

For any elements $a,b$ in a field $F$ and natural numbers $m,n \in \mathbb{N}_\mathbb{R}$
The "natural multiples" $nx$ can be defined inductively by $1\cdot x= x,\: nx  =(n-1)x +x, \: n=1,2, \ldots$
Assume we have shown that:

$ma+na=(m+n)a$;
$ma\cdot nb = (mn)(ab)$;
$n(a\pm b) = na \pm nb$.

Note that, for any ordered field $F$, $1_F>0_F$, along with the fact each natural of $F$ is $\geq 1_F$.
Focusing on the first part, as the last part of question showing that $m<n$ iff $mx <nx$ is a standard induction problem:
Attempted Solution:
Breaking down the problem, we need to first show that each natural element $x$ of an ordered field $F$ can be uniquely represented as $x=n\cdot 1_F$, where $n$ is some natural number in $\mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $1_F$ is the unity in $F$.
To create a sound inductive proposition $P(n)$ we need to make sure that, it includes these conditions:

Existence: for each $x \in \mathbb{N}_F$, we have some $n \in \mathbb{N}_\mathbb{R}$, such that $x=n\cdot 1_F \in \mathbb{N}_F$. Call the $x$, $x_n$, i.e., $x_n :=n\cdot 1_F$.
Uniqueness: this representation of $x$ is unique, i.e., If $m$ is some natural number of $\mathbb{N}_\mathbb{R}$, then, $m\cdot 1_F = n\cdot 1_F \implies m=n$. In other words, if $x_n=x_m \implies n=m$.


Base Case ($P(1)$):

Existence: $x_1 = 1\cdot 1_F =1_F$, by the definition of natural multiplies, and by construction, $1_F \in \mathbb{N}_F$, thus $x_1$ exists. Coming from the other direction, $1_F$ is the smallest natural of element of $F$, by the definition of natural multiplies, $1_F=1\cdot 1_F= x_1$, thus the smallest natural element of $F$, can be represented by this form.
Uniqueness: We need to show that there is no $m \in \mathbb{N}_\mathbb{R}$ such that $m\neq 1$, and $m\cdot 1_F=1_F$. From the properties of naturals, $m\geq 1$, but from the condition $m\neq 1$, $m$ would have to be $>1$. We will show, by induction, that for all $m>1$, it is never the case that $m\cdot 1_F=1_F$.

Taking advantage of the order of $F$, we can set the inductive proposition, $U(n)$, to be true when $n\cdot 1_F >1_F$, given $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $n>1$

$U(2)$ is true; for $n=2$, we have, $2\cdot 1_F= 1_F +1_F$, by the definition of natural multiplies. But, because $1_F>0$, $2\cdot 1_F= 1_F+1_F> 1_F$, by the monotonicity of addition in an ordered field. Thus, $2\cdot 1_F>1_F$.
$U(k)\implies U(k+1)$; Given that $U(n)$ holds for $n=k$, we have $k\cdot 1_F>1_F$, again, by the monotonicity of addition in an ordered field, we have $k\cdot 1_F+1_F>1_F+1_F$, by the definition of natural multiplies, we have $(k+1)\cdot 1_F>2\cdot 1_F$, but we have already shown that $2\cdot 1_F > 1_F$, thus, by the transitive property of $F$, $(k+1)\cdot 1_F>1_F$.

Hence, by induction, we can conclude that there does not exist $m\neq 1$, such that $m\cdot 1_F=1_F$. Thus, We have shown the Uniqueness.

Inductive Step ($P(k)\implies P(k+1)$):
Given $P(k)$ holds, $x_k = k\cdot 1_F \in \mathbb{N}_F$, and $k\cdot 1_F$ is a unique representation.

Existence: because, $x_k = k\cdot 1_F \in \mathbb{N}_{F}$, by the property of any natural element, $x_k+1_F$ is also a natural of $F$, hence $k\cdot 1_F+1_F \in \mathbb{N}_F$. By the definition of natural multiplies, $k\cdot 1_F+1_F = (k+1)\cdot 1_F = x_{k+1} \in \mathbb{N}_F$. Thus, we have shown that $x_{k+1}$ is also a natural of $F$ if $x_k$ is.
Uniqueness: given $n=k$, for any $m\in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{R}}$, $m\cdot 1_F = k\cdot 1_F \implies m=k$. Adding $1_F$, to both sides of the inductive hypothesis's conditional:
\begin{align*}
   k\cdot 1_F +1_F &= m\cdot 1_F +1_F\\
   (k+1)\cdot 1_F &= (m+1)\cdot 1_F 
  \end{align*}
by the definition of natural multiples. Note that the conditional of the inductive hypothesis still holds, hence, as does the implication, that is $k=m$, then, adding $1$ to both sides, $k+1= m+1$. because $m$ is arbitrary, we have $(k+1)\cdot 1_F = m_F\cdot 1_F \implies k+1=m_F$. Hence, $x_{k+1}=(k+1)\cdot 1_F$ is unique if $x_k$ is unique.


Thus, by the principle of mathematical induction, each natural $x$ of $\mathbb{N}_F$ has a unique representation of the form $x=n\cdot 1_F$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{R}} $ and $1_F$ is the unity of $F$. We have also shown the existence of each $x_n = n\cdot 1_F$ in $F$ as its natural elements.
Note that, for any $x \in F$, and any $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{R}}$, $nx \in F$. We can easily show that this holds for all $n$ by induction. The Base case, by definition of natural multiples, holds. If the proposition holds for some $n=k$, $kx \in F$. Then by the definition of natural multiplies, $(k+1)x = kx+x$. Because $kx \in F$ and $x \in F$, by the closure property of all fields, $kx+x \in F$.
Questions:

Is the reasoning sound or even necessary? Specifically the inductive argument for $m>1 \implies m\cdot 1_F > 1_F$
From this solution, can we conclude that there is an isomorphism between the naturals of $\mathbb{R}$ and the naturals of any ordered field $F$? As, there is a unique mapping between the naturals of $\mathbb{R}$ and the naturals of $F$, along with the preservation of $+, \times$ along with the order also being preserved.

Edit: Made the Question more focused

Hi! Please only ask one question at a time. Also, I'll have to quote from the solution-verification tag description: '"Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.' Please identify a specific doubt, if proof correctness is what you're going to ask about.

Have specificed that I am in doubt about the validity of the inductive argument to prove the uniqueness of the representation $x=n\cdot 1_F$, in the base case where $n=1$. The other two questions are about the consequence of the proof and on the general context respectively.

Your proof by induction is incorrect. The statement you want to prove if "for all $x$, there exists $n$, …", which is not under a form that makes it provable by induction; it would need to be "for all $n$, …". Instead, to prove that every natural element can be written $n ⋅ 1_F$, you can simply show that the set ${n ⋅ 1_F, n ∈ ℕ}$ is inductive.

@RagemprandHrekt You should probably cut "Is the reasoning sound or even necessary?" from the first question, then. As for focus, as you say there's 3 questions here, the first two of which are admittedly somewhat closely related. Let me take No. 2 of your hands: If your solution was complete, then yes, this would follow. As for No. 3, the material in your question is sound, but questions about the qualities of certain books are generally off-topic on this site.

@BenSteffan Noted. Will edit the question accordingly.

@JeanAbouSamra I may be interpreting the question too literally but I think we can indeed prove the statement "for each $x$, there exists a $n$,..." by perhaps reframing the statement as "for each $n_F$, there exists a $n$, such that, ...". With this we can start with the base case, i.e., the smallest natural of $F$ is $1_F$ which can be represented by $1\cdot 1_Fhere$. We then show the uniqueness of the representation. Then, for the inductive step, assume $n_F$ can be uniquely represented by $n \cdot 1_F$, we would then need to prove this for $(n+1)_F$. Would this work here?

No, it doesn't work: you are implicitly assuming every $x$ can be written $n_F$, but this is more or less what you want to prove to begin with.

@JeanAbouSamra How about this characterization: "first natural of $F$", "$n$th natural of $F$"?

How do you prove that there exists an $n$-th natural in $F$? This doesn't follow automatically from having an order (e.g., there is no first positive real).

@JeanAbouSamra What if we define the $n$th natural as a sum of $n$ $1_F$s. Also we can assume that $1_F$ is the smallest natural, and because of order, $1_F+1_F> 1_F$.

If you define the $n$-th natural as $\underbrace{1_F + … + 1_F}_{\text{n times}}$, then you have to somehow prove that every $x$ is the $n$-th natural for some $n$, which isn't automatic. At some point you have to use the definition of the natural elements set.

As explained in the comments, you cannot prove something by induction on $n$ if it is not of the form "for all $n$, …".
Here is a short and correct proof:

Let us show that any natural element can be written $n ⋅ 1_F$, i.e., that $N ⊆ \{n ⋅ 1_F, n ∈ ℕ_ℝ\}$. By definition of $N$ as the intersection of inductive subsets, it suffices to prove that $\{n ⋅ 1_F, n ∈ ℕ_ℝ\}$ is inductive, which holds because $1_F = 1 ⋅ 1_F$, and for all $n$, $n ⋅ 1_F + 1_F = (n+1) ⋅ 1_F$.

Let us show that the representation $n ⋅ 1_F$ is unique: Let $n, n'$ be such that $n ⋅ 1_F = n' ⋅ 1_F$. Without loss of generality, assume $n ≥ n'$. Then $(n-n') ⋅ 1_F = 0_F$. To conclude, it suffices to show that $k ⋅ 1_F ≠ 0_F$ for all $k ∈ ℕ_ℝ, k ≠ 0$, which we can do by proving the stronger statement $k ⋅ 1_F > 0$ using induction: for $k = 1$, it is $1_F > 0_F$ which holds by the ordered field axioms, and for the induction step, assuming $k ⋅ 1_F > 0$, we deduce $(k+1) ⋅ 1_F = k ⋅ 1_F + 1_F > k ⋅ 1_F + 0_F = k ⋅ 1_F$.

Let us show by induction that each element $n ⋅ 1_F$ is natural. We need to prove that $n ⋅ 1_F$ belongs to every inductive set. For $n = 0$, this holds as every inductive set contains $0_F$ by definition. For the inductive step, assume $n ⋅ 1_F$ belongs to every inductive set, then $(n+1) ⋅ 1_F = n ⋅ 1_F + 1_F$ again belongs to every inductive set by the definition of inductive sets.



This answer makes much more sense. For your third point, we need to start with $n=1$ though as $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\mathbb{R}}$. Zakon has defined that $1_F$ belongs in each inductive set. Regardless, this is a minor detail.
